# C++ code using GLFW3 on Maverick: glShaderSource no matching function

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glfw

I am trying to compile a fairly simple C++ program using the library GLFW3 on Mac. The OS is OS 10.9.3 (Maverick). It compiles fine until I try to use GLSL functions such as glShaderSource, etc.

Here are the include files I use:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
```

I am using OpenGL3.2:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Here is the command line to compile the program:

```
clang++ -o xxxx xxxx.cpp  -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL  -Wall -lglfw3 -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib  -framework Quartz -framework IOKit
```

And now the error:

```
xxxx:38:5: error: no matching function for call to 'glShaderSource'
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
```

I am sure I missing something basic but what? Thanks for your help. I fear it has something to do with glext but not sure what to do really. I couldn't find anything on Stackoverflow on the web.

Comment: GLFW does not expose any OpenGL function to your app. For that you will need something like GLEW: http://glew.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @glampert: Mac OS has headers with the necessary OpenGL function definitions. No need for GLEW. We're not talking about Windows here...

Comment: "We're not talking about Windows here", I laughed :P

Comment: Reto's answer is perfect, informative, complete and it worked for me. So that's the solution. I had to insert the header. Thanks again, I am always impressed by the kindness of people on Stackoverflow, ready to share their knowledge and spend time answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OS X, you need to include `<OpenGL/gl3.h>` to get definitions for GL3+ level entry points.

In the GLFW documentation, on the page "Building programs that use GLFX" (http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html), there is a section named "GLFW header option macros". The relevant sections are:

> These macros may be defined before the inclusion of the GLFW header and affect the behavior of the header.
>
> GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB makes the header include the modern GL/glcorearb.h header (OpenGL/gl3.h on OS X) instead of the regular OpenGL header.

So the following should do the trick:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

Looking at the `glfw3.h` header (http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/glfw3_8h_source.html) confirms that it will include `<OpenGL/gl3.h>` with this additional define.

Comment: Thank you very much. I looked at the GLFW3 doc but missed this part.   It's great, thanks again.