# OpenGL functions not defined OSX

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I've recently bought a mac to do some cross-platform development and I've got some problems with OpenGL.

Use of undeclared identifier 'glBindVertexArray'

I'm using glfw3 (glfw3.h) with glew (glew.h) and this is how i have it included in code:

```
#ifdef WIN_32
#include <glew.h>
#endif
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <gl/glew.h>
#endif

#define GLEW_STATIC

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB

#include "glfw3.h"
```

Any obvious errors as to why I'm getting these undefined identifiers?

Comment: There's no need for GLEW on OS X. It has all the headers and libraries for the supported OpenGL versions. Does it work if you simply remove the include of `<gl/glew.h>`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately no it doesn't work after removing GLEW. Good to know it's not needed though.

Comment: Weird. This just came up a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664722/c-code-using-glfw3-on-maverick-glshadersource-no-matching-function/. For that poster, it worked after adding the `GLFW_INCLUDE_COREARB` define.

Comment: Ah, do I need to put GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB in front of EVERY include of glfw3? Or just the first one?

Comment: Hmm that seemed to solve it, does that sound about right?

Comment: Yes, if you include the glfw3 headers in multiple source files, you'll need the define every time. What I typically do when writing cross platform code, is to define my own header file (e.g. named `gl_headers.h`) that conditionally includes the platform specific GL headers. Then I only include my own header in the rest of the code, and the platform dependency of the needed include files is isolated in a single place.

Comment: Great idea, If you want to post that as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need GLEW on OS X. All supported OpenGL functions are declared in header files that are included with the standard development environment. If you want to see what header files are present, and what they contain, the exact location of the header files is explained in this answer: [Where are the OpenGL header files located on MacOSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197223/where-are-the-opengl-header-files-located-on-macosx/23576954#23576954). You don't normally have to worry about the path name, the compiler will find the right one automatically if you include it with a name like `<OpenGL/gl3.h>`.

For GLFW, you had the right include sequence in your question:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

What you were missing based on the discussion in the comments is that you need the `GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB` define **every time** before you include `<GLFW/glfw3.h>`.

When you develop cross platform code, needing conditional includes for each platform in every source file that contains OpenGL calls is cumbersome to maintain. A simple approach to make life easier is to keep the system dependent includes in a single header, and then include that header in your source files. This isolates the system dependencies, and will make it much easier to for example add a platform later.

For example, you could define a header named `gl_includes.h`, which includes the system dependent OpenGL includes, like you have it in your code:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#include ...
#endif

#ifdef ...
#include ...
#endif
```

Then, in all your source files, you only include this header:

```
#include "gl_includes.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `CC=clang++`, add `-isysroot` to your argument

Example, in my makefile:

```
CC=clang++
CFLAGS:= -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
```